# Why did the First Order land AT-M6s so far away from the blast doors?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In the end of *Star Wars: The Last Jedi*, we saw a battle similar to

> Battle of Hoth. But, unlike Battle of Hoth, nobody was even firing from enemy side in the beginning.

Why didn't First Order land AT-M6s near blast doors instead of moving slowly towards it such that enemies had enough time to mount a little resistance to delay them?

Comment: Because they needed time to get that big gun linked up to the crawlers?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is addressed in the film's [Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary). Recognising that a siege is taking place, the First Order airlifts a bunker-buster to the battlefield. This **Superlaser Siege Cannon** is a highly vulnerable piece of kit while it's charging (and apparently has a line-of-sight range) so the goal is to keep it safe until it can be used at least once. This means landing *outside the range of the Resistance's gun emplacements.*

[image]

<sub><sup>*"To penetrate the Resistance defences, the First Order airlifts a massive superlaser siege cannon to Crait's surface. Towed by tug walkers,
the enormous 200-metre-long weapon is a piece of miniaturised Death Star technology. A fiery tracer beam creates a path along which a devastating pulse travels towards the target, detonating with terrifying impact. **The cannon requires time to charge up between blasts, however, during which time it is vulnerable, necessitating escort walkers and air support."***</sup></sub>

Comment: This seems to be a better answer than suggesting that the shield is preventing a closer landing, since we later see TIE fighters (and the Falcon) flying through the airspace closer to the base.

Would have liked the "miniaturized Death Star technology" to project a superlaser-green beam.

Comment: "*outside the range of the Resistance's gun emplacements.*" any competent commander would protect something as important as the SSC with radar-guided counter-battery artillery.

Comment: I think any laser weapon is going to be line of sight range.

Comment: @JeremyFrench - Indeed. But most weapons in Star Wars are plasma based and travel about as far as a bullet.

Comment: I think any serious analysis of Star Wars weapon ranges is going to run into confusion as soon as you recall that the cannon firing on the Resistance cruiser were lobbing shells that curved in graceful ballistic arcs... in space.

Comment: @anaximander - Yeah, but it looked amazing. Which is the entire point of a film

Comment: Why couldn't they keep it charged in transit, land it right by the blast doors and fire as soon as it is on the ground? For the drama of course.

Comment: @AytAyt - Because they want to fire it more than once. Imagine if it didn't cut through on the first firing. Now it's entirely vulnerable.

Comment: @Valorum same as if they walked it up to fire it. When i said right at the doors, i just meant in range (so, in view)

Comment: But squire55's answer prevents that

Comment: @AytAyt Even in our real world, keeping massive, highly-destructive hardware primed, charged, and ready to fire at a moment's notice is often a bad idea. I don't know how that cannon works internally or how they brought it down from orbit, but let's just say that if that thing was charged *before* loading onto a lander, I'd want to be riding on a different lander. Preferably one far, *far* away.

Comment: @anaximander that's a very very good point i hadn't considered haha.

Comment: @anaximander And the scene with the bombers earlier in the film gave a very good example of *why* that can be a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

Same reason the First Order couldn't shoot the base from orbit. As the rebels were occupying the base, one of them mentioned that the shields will stop us being shot from space. Presumably the shield boundary extends out into the salt plain a short distance to prevent the First Order doing a closer landing. 
Presumably the same shields do not stop you moving through them with your walkers and your battering ram cannon.

Also, like the battle of Hoth, this is Star Wars canon, and it is just the way things are done.

Comment: "*this is Star Wars canon, and it is just the way things are done.*"  I wish I could vote this +10.  If matter like walkers can pass through the shield, then you can drop a *rod from God* on the door.

Comment: Large-area shields like the ones covering the planetary base seem to be more effective against things that are fast-moving. Shields are also shown to be directional (a few times, ships have been instructed to direct power to shields in a certain direction), and it makes sense that a shield covering a surface base would be focused on attack from above, given that space-based weaponry is the most dangerous. Given these two points, the easiest way to penetrate a shield is therefore to come in slowly from low angle, which is what the walkers do.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with speed. The blocking power of a shield is directly proportional to the speed of the incoming object. Projectiles, meteors and especially light (lasers) are moving fast enough to get blocked by a shield, but of course the energy required to do the blocking is also proportional to the energy of the object being blocked, and that energy is turned into heat at the point of contact, and this heat can and will cause damage to a ship inside a shield bubble if intense enough.

A slow moving object (like an imperial walker) should be able to penetrate a shield, and once inside it can do its damage. A siege cannon slowly dragged into position can also penetrate a shield this way, and being inside its laser energy can used much more effectively to punch a hole in a heavily fortified door or similar.

Comment: Do you have any canon evidence for the fact that the blocking power of a shield is directly proportional to the speed of the incoming object? Kylo's fighter got through the cruiser shields pretty easily...

Comment: Kylo's fighter as well as our heroes got inside with high speed..

Comment: I just remembered Goaul'd shields...